# Append <div> to all <div>s with class x, except

Tags: html, jquery

I want to insert a new div on all div s with class 'image', but with some exceptions.

```
$("<div>— hold to read</div>").appendTo('.image')
```

Between these I also have some divider images, also with .image class (added by Wordpress automatically), but which shouldn't have that `<div>` inside.

How can I write the above but with this exception? I can target the ones that need out based on a link with a title inside eg `('.image > a[title="divider-picture"]')`

THIS SHOULD HAVE

```
<div class="image">

<a itemprop="image" title="main-picture" data-rel="prettyPhoto[single_pretty_photo]" href="#">

<img itemprop="image" src="#" alt="main">

</a>

<div class="img__label_layer">— hold to read</div>
<span class="holdtoview"><div class="actionin">TEXT</div></span>

</div>
```

THIS SHOULDN'T

```
<div class="image">

<a itemprop="image" title="divider-picture" data-rel="prettyPhoto[single_pretty_photo]" href="#">

<img itemprop="image" src="#" alt="div">

</a>

<div class="img__label_layer">— hold to read</div>
<span class="holdtoview"><div class="actionin">TEXT</div></span>

</div>
```

Thanks

Comment: Can you please add the HTML, that would help addressing your issue.

Comment: I'm sorry, I've added the html, hope is more clear.

Comment: I would think `.image:not(.some-other-criteria)`.

Comment: In your example  is no div with the class "image" without an <a title="divider-picture"> in it, so where should the <div>- hold to read</div> be appended to?

Comment: Added another piece of html.  The first example should have the new div, the second shouldn't. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do it like this: use `not()` and `has()` to select all `<div>` elements that have the class `image` that don't have a child `<a>` with the attribute `title="divider-picture"

```js
$("<div>— hold to read</div>").appendTo('div.image:not(:has( a[title="divider-picture"]))');
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="image">

<a itemprop="image" title="main-picture" data-rel="prettyPhoto[single_pretty_photo]" href="#">

<img itemprop="image" src="#" alt="main">

</a>

<div class="img__label_layer">— hold to read</div>
<span class="holdtoview"><div class="actionin">TEXT</div></span>

</div>
<div class="image">

  <a itemprop="image" title="divider-picture" data-rel="prettyPhoto[single_pretty_photo]" href="#">

    <img itemprop="image" src="#" alt="div8">

  </a>

  <div class="img__label_layer">— hold to read</div>
  <span class="holdtoview">
    <div class="actionin">TEXT</div>
  </span>

</div>
```

`:

Answer (score 0):

Use the [`:not()`](https://api.jquery.com/not-selector/) selector or the [`.not()` method](https://api.jquery.com/not/).

```js
$(function() {
  $('<div>Inserted</div>').appendTo('.image:not(.skip)')
})
```

```css
.image {
  border: 1px solid red;
  padding: 5px;
  margin: 5px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="image">Image</div>
<div class="image">Image</div>
<div class="image skip">Image</div>
<div class="image">Image</div>
```

Also, it may be you want to omit ones that have a specific child. Here's one way.

```js
$(function() {
    $('<div class="insert">Inserted</div>').appendTo(
    $('.image').not($('.image:has(.skip)'))
  )
})
```

```css
.image {
  border: 1px solid red;
  padding: 5px;
  margin: 5px;
}
.insert {
  border: 1px solid blue;
  padding: 5px;
  margin: 5px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="image">Image</div>
<div class="image">Image</div>
<div class="image">
  <span class="skip">Skip</span>
  Image
</div>
<div class="image">Image</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`.not()`](https://api.jquery.com/not/) with [`.has()`](https://api.jquery.com/has/) to achieve this in jQuery:

```js
var el = $("<div>— hold to read</div>");
$('.image').not().has('[title="divider-picture"]').prepend(el)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="image">

<a itemprop="image" title="main-picture" data-rel="prettyPhoto[single_pretty_photo]" href="#">

<img itemprop="image" src="#" alt="main">

</a>

<span class="holdtoview"><div class="actionin">TEXT</div></span>

</div>


<div class="image">

<a itemprop="image" title="divider-picture" data-rel="prettyPhoto[single_pretty_photo]" href="#">

<img itemprop="image" src="#" alt="div">

</a>
<span class="holdtoview"><div class="actionin">TEXT</div></span>

</div>
```